# In-App auto-renewable subscription for multiple user items(iOS)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

We are developing a product where it needs In-App auto-renewable subscription for the product on iOS platform. Trying to understand whether this model works with In-App purchase?

**Here is the example:**

User creates an Item A, use post the item A to rent the product for users. For posting the product we would like to charge $9.99 per week on auto-renewable subscription.

User creates an Item B, use post the item B to renting the product for users. For posting the product we would like to charge $9.99 per week on auto-renewable subscription.

My question is, can user post n number of items with $9.99 per week on auto-renewable subscription? How do we set this up in iTunes connect for n number of items for one auto renewable subscription.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't use auto-renewing IAPs for this sort of application - You would need to add an additional IAP and submit it for review each time a new item was posted.   You can probably use non-renewing subscription IAPs and you will be responsible for tracking which item(s) the user has subscribed to.

Comment: You can not use this type of case with in app purchase, user can not decide the product or services for In-App auto-renewable. only app agent can add and also product or services will have to approved by apple .